# Dynamic css in lightning

Tags: lightning, css

I have some iteration in code and i want to have some css only on every second element, except last one.

So in angular i would do something like that:

```
<div ng-repeat="n in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] track by $index">
<some-element ng-class="($index % 2 === 0 
    && $index + 1 !== element.length) ? 'black' : 'white'" />
</div>
```

How can i achieve the same in lightning?

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.questions}" var="question">

  <lightning:layoutItem flexibility="auto" padding=" HERE WE WANT DYNAMIC CSS ">
    <lightning:select name="answer" label="{!question.Name}" disabled="{!question.Id != v.recordId}" value="{!question.AnswerValue__c}" >

     <!-- some code here -->

   </lightning:select>
  </lightning:layoutItem>
</aura:iteration>
```

**UPD:**
Ok, this version work

```
<lightning:layoutItem padding="{! index % 2 == 1 ? 'horizontal-small' : ''}">
```

But once i add && with second expression, im getting error:

```
<lightning:layoutItem flexibility="auto" padding="{! index % 2 == 1 && index != v.questions.size ? 'horizontal-small' : ''}">
```

> Error:(49, 10):49,102: ParseError at
>   [row,col]:[50,102] Message: The entity name must immediately follow
>   the '&' in the entity reference.

Comment: You can use `indexVar` to know the count of element in [`aura:Iteration`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_tag_iteration.htm) and based on it make your CSS dynamic

Comment: try brackets (index % 2 == 1 && index != v.questions.size)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`indexVar` attribute is helpful in identifying the index of iteration in [`aura:iteration`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_tag_iteration.htm). Tried to modify example based on your example:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.questions}" var="question" indexVar="index">
    <lightning:layoutItem flexibility="auto" 
        class="{!(index % 2 == 0 &amp;&amp; index + 1 != v.questions.length) ? 
            'black' : 'white'}">
        <!-- some code -->
    </lightning:layoutItem>
</aura:iteration>
```

Note: Data type of `indexVar` is string so be careful when you do [an exact type check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons). inside the merge field in component it doesn't like `&&`, hence we need `&amp;&amp;` for specifying AND operation.

Answer (score 2):

This is your syntax

```
<lightning:layoutItem padding="{! trueFalseExpression ? 'around-small' : '' }">
```

This is the [official reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_conditional.htm)